# RTC build definition invoking antoher build definition

Tags: build, build-process, rtc

I have one requirement of one build definition should invoke the other build definition.

Based on the result of the first one, the second one should get triggered.

Is there any option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the article "
[How to keep your streams flowing smoothly in Rational Team Concert 3.0.1](https://jazz.net/library/article/649)", you could set up the [post-build deliver step](https://jazz.net/library/article/649#Example_postBuildDeliver) in order to deliver to another stream, monitor by another build.

If the first build goes well, it delivers to the second stream, which is monitored by a build workspace associated to a second build, which will start then.

Note that only a [RTC 4.0.6+ (February 2014) allows to fine-tuned](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/4.0.6?p=news#udeploy) the conditions for which a post-build deliver will be triggered.